# How to post like/unlike to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

How to send "like" to user activity from android application ? Is there is a way to compose `Graph API` `POST` request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *"Like"* A Post:

```
Request reqlike = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), postID + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        // PARSE THE "response" TO CHECK FOR ERRORS OR SHOW A SUCCESS MESSAGE OR SOMETHING
    }
}); Request.executeBatchAndWait(reqlike);
```

To *"Unlike"* A Post:

```
Request reqUnlike = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), postID + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        // PARSE THE "response" TO CHECK FOR ERRORS OR SHOW A SUCCESS MESSAGE OR SOMETHING
    }
}); Request.executeBatchAndWait(reqUnlike);
```

The two key things to note here are (In the `new Request()` constructor):

1. `postID + "/likes"`
2. `null`

**First:** Either the Graph API endpoint can be as shown in the example. Or it can be something like `"1234567890/likes"` where *1234567890* is an imaginary Post ID. I suspect, the usage shown in the example will most likely be used considering that you would typically be dealing with dynamic feeds off the Facebook API.

**Second:** Since we are not passing any parameters via a Bundle instance, an explicit `null` will have to be passed.

Comment: Hi, i try to use this method, but im always getting a nullpointerexception as Facebook Response.

Comment: it's not working for me every time return Null Pointer Exception i hope to help me thanks.

Comment: Need to pass URL as a param

Comment: @AJit: Params in what? In a _Like_ or an _Unlike_?

Comment: like=post method and unlike=delete method, both need to pass proper url, i.e <post_id>/likes.. probably gives an error because you are passing null in <post_id>

Comment: @AJit: If you read the explanation properly, you will see that the `null` part has been explained. As far as I know, (_and the code still works_) no URL needs to be passed because all necessary details such as the **post id** and the `.POST` to _like_ and `.DELETE` to _unlike_ are already in the `Request` constructor. But, feel free to post a new, more correct answer, if you feel this is wrong or obsolete.